# Mapreduce multiple map and redcuer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am thinking to  process CSV files, each size around 1 Mb using MapReduce  which has data like

```
 lat , lng
18.123, 77.312
18.434,77,456
18,654,77,483
....
....
```

I want to keep mapper and reducer count upon no. of input files.

```
fil1->map1->redcuer1-<output1
  fil2->map2->redcuer2-<output2
  .....
  ....
```

Although for my Mapper input is key->filename, value->18.123, 77.312
But i needed to calculate Distance from first record  and second one

```
i.e Geo Distance for 1st record -> 18.123, 77.312 and 18.434,77,456
                     2nd record -> 18.123, 77.312 and 18.434,77,456
```

In Mapper i get one line of csv file is readed at a time and pass that to reducer
So i am thinking to concatinate csv file records by delimiter Pipe sign (|)
Above csv data will become as

```
     lat|lng
     18.123, 77.312|18.434,77,456|18,654,77,483|....|....|...
```

In Mapper i will get key->filename and values->All records of csv  with pipe sign
In reducer i will split it and calulate distance and store in Mysql

Is this correct approach or has some other way

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think that 1MB file is big? and yet you want to use Hadoop to process it?

Comment: There are multiple files of size 1 MB each.

Comment: 1MB is too small for Hadoop. You aren't going to have any advantages unless you combine them using the built in Hadoop facilities.

Comment: I had total 70 -80 or more  csv files 1 MB each . The csv file data contains separate geo coordinates. So i am thinking giving to process all files at a time mapper1->reducer1->output1...........mapper80->reducer80->output80

Comment: Keep in mind that in HDFS, the filesystem block size is at least 64MB. It is much better if you treated those 80 files as one.

Comment: Yes, It is possible for combining for me.

Comment: Then go with CombineFileInputFormat